# Array index beyond bounds

Tags: objective-c, arrays

When I run the code below I get

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]
```

I understand that at some point in the loop not existed index of the array is reached.
How to deal with that ?

```
 int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSArray *t = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];

        for(id x in t)
        {
            NSArray *tmpArray = [x componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
               NSLog(@"%@", [tmpArray objectAtIndex:1]);
        }
        [pool drain];
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The indices begin at 0, there may not be anything at index 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all time zones names contain a slash.  For example, the `UTC` time zone name does not contain a slash.  So `tmpArray` might only contain one string, at index 0.

Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
       NSLog(@"%@", [tmpArray lastObject]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the size of `tmpArray` first:

```
NSArray *tmpArray = [x componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
if ([tmpArray count] > 1)
    NSLog(@"%@", [tmpArray objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the size of tmpArray before accessing index 1